# Get all rows through pages in Flexigrid

Tags: jquery, flexigrid

I have to get the rows for export, but I'm only able to get the items on the current page with this code:

```
$('#flex1 tr', grid).each(function() {
arr.push( parseInt($(this).text(),10) );
});
```

But I would like to export the results through pages. I need I solution like this, but this does'nt works:

```
$('#flex1 page', grid).each(function() {
   $('#flex1 tr', grid).each(function() {
       arr.push( parseInt($(this).text(),10) );
   });
});
```

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I think that is not possible because the rows that are only being created when you load the grid or changed records per page are the ones returned by the JSON or XML. So instead of getting the row IDs, you must pass all the grid parameters which you used to filter the records to the server-side script that generates the JSON or XML file.

Hope this make sense :)